# polymorphism with sub-classes of different template type

Tags: c++, class, templates, polymorphism, abstract-class

I've got class with template and some classes inherit from him.
We want to create instance of the father class without declaring its template type, and call a function returning the template type.

Example:

```
class FatherWrap {
    virtual ~FatherWrap() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class FatherClass : public FatherWrap
{
    virtual T getValue();
};

class SonClass1 : public FatherClass<int>
{
    int getValue() override;
};

class SonClass2 : public FatherClass<string>
{
    string getValue() override;
};  

int main()
{
    FatherWrap* ch = new SonClass1();
    T a = ch->getValue; // What to do instead of T.
}
```

Comment: `FatherClass* ch` is invalid, because there is no such class `FatherClass`, in the example shown. It is a template for a class (`FatherClass<int>` is a class, however).

Comment: Please read about the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and try to tell us what you actually want to achieve. What you are asking for is not possible, but maybe we can help with the problem you are actually trying to solve

Comment: I edited the code, my problem is calling getValue from the wrapper.

Comment: If you look at your wrapper now, you'll see that it has no getValue method.

Comment: How about using `auto` at the place of `T`?. Also `FatherWrap` has no function name `getValue()`.

Comment: your small edit changed the meaning of the code completely.... I hope you are not just making this up...

Comment: sorry, but after the edit it is even less clear what the question is about. Instead of `T` you put `int` because `SonClass1::getValue` returns an `int`. (`ch->getValue` should be `ch->getValue()`, no?)

Comment: I want to use polymorphism where one of the class properties type can be different for each sub class.
Then use this property without knowing its type.

Comment: why "without knowing the type" ? In your example you do know the type and in general when you have to know the type, then it isnt really polymorphic....

Comment: The wrapper can't have the function because it doesnt know the type...

Comment: how do you plan to use the return value when you dont know its type?

Comment: just use `std::any` or `std::variant` as a return type. This is still `XY problem`, you are asking how to fix your solution of some mysterious problem. If you could provide what kind of business logic you are trying to achieve then someone could provide better approach.

Comment: lets say i have a base class that represents connecting to a device, and one of its properties is information on how to connect the device - lets call it conn.
this class have sub types - for example - connecting through ip that its conn property is storing a string ("127.0.0.1"), and also there is a class connecting through com port - that its conn property is storing an int (70).
I want to have instance of the base class, and still be able to work with both types from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could skip the `FatherWrap` entirely and make the base class return a variant:

```
struct FatherClass : FatherWrap {
    virtual std::variant<int, std::string> getValue();
};

struct SonClass1 : FatherClass {
    std::variant<int, std::string> getValue() override {
        return "some text";
    }
};

struct SonClass2 : FatherClass {
    std::variant<int, std::string> getValue() override {
        return 95;
    }
};
```

---

Alternatively, you could template any code that uses `SonClass`:

```
struct SonClass1 { // no parent.
    std::string getValue() {
        return "some text";
    }
};

struct SonClass2 { // no parent.
    int getValue() {
        return 95;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void useSonClass(T& son) {
    // value may be int or string.
    auto value = son.getValue();
}

int main() {
    SonClass1 sc1;
    SonClass2 sc2;

    useSonClass(sc1);
    useSonClass(sc2);
}
```

If you want to contain it, just use a variant:

```
int main() {
    std::variant<SonClass1, SonClass2> sc = SonClass2{};

    std::visit(
        [](auto& sc) { useSonClass(sc); },
        sc
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have:

- An unparameterized (no template) base class `B`
- An intermediate template class `I<T>` inheriting from `B`
- Some derived classes `D1`, `D2`, etc. each of which inherits from a specialization of `I`

You want to write some code in terms of `B`. You can do that--but you have to limit yourself to using the API that `B` defines. The methods of `B` can be virtual, and the implementations/overrides of those methods in `I<T>` and `Dx` can use the type `T`, but those types can't be exposed to a component the only knows about `B`.

If you want to write some logic that uses `T`, then that logic needs to be either in a method of `I<T>`, or in a template function that is itself parameterized with a class type:

```
template<class U>
U someTypeSpecificLogic(I<U> intermediate) {
    // can call methods that accept/return U here
}
```

You can't write logic in terms of `B` that depends on the type `T` because that type is only defined for the subclass `I<T>`. Consider that the `B` you have be a *different* subclass of `B` and not an `I<T>` at all.